# Can I make Eclipse change my comments when I rename my classes?

Tags: eclipse, class, refactoring, comments, rename

I am using the refactor rename tool in Eclipse to change my class names, but can I make it change those names in my comments at the same time? I heard it was possible, but my Eclipse doesn't bring up the prompt to ask if I want references in my comments to be changed when I rename the class. Please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use "Refactor - Rename" from the package tree, an options dialog should appear. If you do it from the editor, press the little down arrow in the rename popup, and choose "Open Rename Dialog...".

[image]